# How to read accelelrometer sensor values continously for 5 seconds inside an AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am using `AccessibilityService` to monitor whenever the foreground activity is changed. Additionally whenever a such a change occurs, I need to read the accelerometer readings for the next 5 seconds. I implemented the following code, but I am not getting continuous readings. Sometimes No reading is shown in between 2 app switches

I am able to detect the foreground activity change accurately, and I can run an activity independently that can show the sensor state changes. But problem exists in combining both.

```
public class WindowChangeDetectingService extends AccessibilityService implements SensorEventListener {

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
            ...
    }
    SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor mAccelerometerSensor;
    SensorEventListener mListener;
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {

            try {
                mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mListener);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("not unregs",e.toString());
            }

            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mAccelerometerSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

            Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //    do stuff with sensor values

                    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mListener);
                }
            }, 5000);

            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                    event.getPackageName().toString(),
                    event.getClassName().toString()
            );

            ActivityInfo activityInfo = tryGetActivity(componentName);
            boolean isActivity = activityInfo != null;
            if (isActivity)
                Log.i("CurrentActivity", componentName.flattenToShortString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {}

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
       Log.i("\nAccelerometer: \n","X:"+x+"\tY:"+y+"\tZ:"+z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME` or `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` instead of `SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL`

```
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometerSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, 
          mAccelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);//change here
```

Comment: I was using SENSOR_DELAY_GAME initially. It wasn't giving any improvement.

Comment: normally, sensor is sending data in faster speed ..i.e. within mseconds ?

Comment: I am unregistering after 5 seconds, which means within 5 secods, I should ideally be getting all the readings

Comment: Have you logged the times for Activity creation, Sensor registration and first time sensor data catch by the device...? it will detect the part which is taking the most time.